# Usb C Male to Wall outlet or Dell charger?

Tags: usb

I have a Dell laptop, with the ring shaped charger (not usb-c), I want to be able to charge it trough my giant battery pack, it has usb-c and a. Is there and adapter or wire, so 1 end is usb-c (45w) and other is wall outlet (so I can plug in the wall charger) or directly to dell's charger port?

Comment: @jcam3 frogot to mention https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/usb-c-to-dell-ring-charger-adapter-wire/63151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very bad idea unless you can verify with 100% certainty that the USB-C cable can carry the same amperage and voltage as the laptop charging cable. Missing the mark on this by charging your battery on a connection that has too much or too little juice can damage the battery and present a fire hazard. OEM laptops should always be used with a properly specced charging cable, preferably from the manufacturer.